# Stored procedure to get one year of data splitted per months

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am relatively new to Oracle so i'd really appreciate some help.

I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE date between (date1) and (date2).
```

What I need is to get all the reservations within the interval : today's date and today's date -1 year, so basically 1 year of history.

I want to run the above query with interval of 1 months, and export the query set to excel.
I need some help in the logic of the loop (create a stored procedure or function), as i will think later for the export to excel.

Comment: What do you mean by "splitted per months". Add few sample rows in your table and the output that you want to see.Post only in text format, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give all records from 1 year back to today:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE date >= trunc( sysdate ) - interval '1' year
  AND date < trunc( sysdate ) + interval '1' day
```

---

> I want to run the above query with interval of 1 months,

I understand that you want to run this query 12 times, each time for another monthly period. If yes, then run this query 12 times changing the parameter X (within `SELECT 1 As X FROM dual` subquery), beginning from 12 to 1 (or 1 to 12):

```
SELECT * FROM reservations 
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 1 As X FROM dual
) x
WHERE date >= trunc( sysdate ) - x * interval '1' month
  AND date < trunc( sysdate ) + interval '1' day - ( x - 1 ) * interval '1' month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the procedure to create the queries month-wise starting from sysdate . 

create or replace procedure monthwise_query 
as
t_date DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE) ;
c_date DATE ;
BEGIN

FOR i in 1..12
LOOP
c_date := t_date;

  dbms_output.put_line('select * from reservations where rev_date between to_date('''||c_date||''',''DD-MON-YY'') and (select add_months(to_date('''||c_date||''',''DD-MON-YY''),-1) from dual);');

 select add_months(c_date,-1)  
 into t_date
 from dual;

END LOOP;
END;

- It can be extended with UTIL_FILE utility inside this procedure to write each query result to single/multiple files.

- SPOOL from SQL*plus for each query will be easy

- UNIX script to loop through each monthwise-query to load to file also possible
```